# Martingale Convergence Theorem rational numbers

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

In Durrett’s Probability: Theory and Examples I have found the following proof for the „Martingale convergence theorem“:

[image: from Durrett p. 202, ed. 4.1 (online version)]

My question is about the first part where he says „Since the last conclusion holds for all rational a and b, …“. Why does it hold for all rationals? This probably has some measure theoretic reason which I couldn't figure out.

Comment: The statement holds for any real numbers and hence in particular for all rationals. Where exactly is your problem with that...?

Comment: If you're wondering why he considers _only_ rationals, as opposed to all reals, there is a measure-theoretic reason: it's so that the union is countable.

Comment: @aduh: Why do we want the union to be countable?

Comment: A countable union of null events is null. An uncountable union of null events could have positive probability.